# Quiero Hacer click en un item y Realizar cambios en otro Con RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Quiero que Al hacer Click Sobre un item En el otro item Tenga un cambio Algo como que si yo presiono sobre un item del RecyclerView en el otro se oculte el texto algo parecido a eso creen que hay alguna forma de hacerlo
Bueno tengo un RecyclerView Con 3 ítems al pulsar sobre un item quiero otro item Tenga cambios Ejemplo los ítems tienen un textView que indica el nombre del item al pulsar sobre el item 2 quiero que el texto del item 1 se cambie y viceversa

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Bueno tengo un RecyclerView Con 3 ítems al pulsar sobre un item quiero otro item Tenga cambios
Ejemplo los ítems tienen un textView que indica el nombre del item al pulsar sobre el item 2 quiero que el texto del item 1 se cambie y viceversa